# ogr2ogr shapefile to PostgreSQL table | cannot change geom field

Tags: python, ogr2ogr, batch

```
ogr2ogr -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=localhost user=postgres dbname=lidar password=postgres" "C:/Users/Rose/Documents/faulty_rasters_test/raster_summary/gdaltindex/1.shp" -lco FID=gid -lco PRECISION=yes -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -nln lidar.test_dem
```

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=localhost user=postgres dbname=lidar password=postgres" "C:/Users/Rose/Documents/faulty_rasters_test/raster_summary/gdaltindex/1.shp" -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -lco FID=gid -lco PRECISION=yes -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -nln lidar.test_dem
```

Used above to import shapefile into PostgreSQL database, using python.subprocess() and batch shell.
No sterr messages were outputted e.g.
[image: Python output]

The PostgreSQL table was created but the geom column was incorrect.

The geom column was still the default (wkb_geometry), even though it was specified in command.
Using PostgreSQL 11.8, pgAdmin 4.20, Python 3.8 e.g.

[image: PostgreSQL Table ogr2ogr output]

How do I change this in this command? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It does definitely work for me. My steps follow:

GDAL version 3.0.4
PostgreSQL version 12.4
PostGIS version 3.0

I created a new schema "lidar" into an existing db. I concluded that your aim is to write table "test_dem" into schema "lidar" in db "lidar" so I tested the same.

I took your command and modified it a bit

```
ogr2ogr -lco GEOMETRY_NAME=geom -f "PostgreSQL" "PG:host=localhost user=test dbname=lidar password=testpw" "c:\data\nametest.shp" -lco FID=gid -lco PRECISION=yes -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -nln lidar.test_dem
```

Then I executed it without Python and the geometry name in PostGIS is "geom".

[image: New table in PostGIS]

I wonder if you have an old table remaining from your previous experiments. If you run the command with Python you may not notice the warning that ogr2ogr sends in such case:

```
Warning 1: Layer creation options ignored since an existing layer is being appended to.
```

Comment: Glad it's working for you outside python. I couldn't help but notice, this is exactly the same command as the first example in my question I also outputted standard sterr from the subprocess as above?

Comment: Does it work for you outside Python?

Answer (score 0):

This happens on newly created database where `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;` has not yet been executed.